# Table View Cell Height using Row Height not Auto Layout Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have 3 custom Table View Cell's in a `UITableView`.  I have the the height of one cell perfect, but the **other two cells I just want them to use AutoLayout for their height**.

This is what I have, does anyone have another idea for the `else` statement?:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id model = self.Model[indexPath.row];

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[D self]]) {
        ListTableViewCell *cellOne = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"1Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!cellOne) {
            cellOne = [[ListTableViewCell alloc] init];

            FR *fD = (FR *)model;
            NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.title];
            NSString *dateString = [self timeSincePublished:fD.pubDate];
            NSString *description = [self removeHTMLTags:fD.description];
            NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fD.link];

            cellOne.labelHeadline.text = title;
            cellOne.labelDescription.text = description;
            cellOne.labelPublished.text = dateString;
        }

        // Make sure the cell's frame is updated
        [cellOne setNeedsLayout];
        [cellOne layoutIfNeeded];

        CGFloat heightOne = [cellOne.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
        return heightOne + 2;

    } else {

    // This is where I need help for other 2 custom cells to just use AutoLayout height
    return tableView.rowHeight;

}
```

Right now, `return tableView.rowHeight` is returning the hardcoded height that is set in the storyboard, regardless of how much is actually in the cell.

[image]

**It should ignore that height and just use AutoLayout.**

Do you know a way to do that?  Thanks!  Will gladly post any extra info if needed-

Comment: You can't do that with autolayout. The cells always have a fixed height. this is the purpose of the tableview, to scroll the cells if too much or too big.

Comment: @DavidAnsermot so for AutoLayout the cells always have a fixed height?  I guess I'm not following

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With auto layout you don't use `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Instead you can use something like this:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Comment: Then it must be an issue with your layout constraints.